# "Было кучу времени", "было пару человек". Именительный или и вправду винительный?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи

Часто слышу, как в некоторых фразах (сейчас я приведу примеры) употребляют винительный падеж вместо именительного.

Например, часто говорят *"У меня был**о** куч**у** времени на то, чтобы..."* вместо *"У меня был**а** куч**а** времени..."* Вот это, похоже, действительно неправильно. Google вроде это тоже подтверждает.

А как быть с этим: *"Там был**а** пар**а** человек"* правильно или всё-таки должно быть *"Там было пару человек"?* Казалось, совсем запутался, но когда писал второе, подумал, что нет, точно не так. С другой стороны, и первое звучит не очень, прежде всего потому, что от других такого обычно не слышишь.

Comment: "У меня было кучу времени на то, чтобы..." вместо "У меня была куча времени..." Вот это, похоже, действительно неправильно.
И "Там было пару человек" тоже неправильно. Это субъект, субъект задается именительным падежом. Ни разу не слышала фразы "У меня было кучу времени на то, чтобы...", не знаю, почему Вы такое услышали. Мне обе фразы режут слух.

Comment: "...не знаю, почему Вы такое услышали". Кто-то сказал — вот поэтому и услышал))), да притом далеко не один раз. Я так же рассуждал, да и говорил на автомате, как и Вы, но то, что я постоянно слышу по-другому, меня постепенно начало настораживать и возбуждать сомнения.

Comment: почему Вы такое услышали - почему они так сказали. :-)
Оффтоп. Из замеченого мной - люди стали говорить "сколько время", а не "сколько времени"...

Comment: Да, это ужасно!((

Comment: Кстати, прикол. Когда моего дядю спрашивают "Ты мне позвОнишь?", он отвечает "ПозвОню". ;)

Comment: А если дядю спросить: "Ты свАришь суп?", он ответит "СвАрю"?

Comment: Конечно, нет! ;) В этом случае намёк, а в Вашем — и намекать не на что, так что зачем это.

Comment: Довольно интересно, что, согласно традициям эволюции русского языка, ударение в слове "звонить" давно уже должно было переместиться в центр слова, на букву "о". Однако, это слово является настолько мощным социальным индикатором, что вряд ли это произойдёт в ближайшее время.

Answer (score 1):

[Вот](https://iling.spb.ru/confs/rusconstr2011/pdf/XolodilovaLetuchiy.pdf) научная статья про пару человек. Привожу полностью.

М. А. Холодилова, СПбГУ, Санкт-Петербург

А. Б. Летучий, ИРЯ РАН, Москва

**Было пару человек: об одной количественной конструкции в русском языке**

*В нашем докладе мы расскажем об одной особенности поведения квантификаторов типа пара, куча, масса в русском языке.*

Квантификаторы этой группы рассматриваются в диссертации [Ли Су Хён 2005] и в статье [Рахилина, Ли Су Хён 2009]. В данных работах, среди прочего, показано, что в квантитативных употреблениях значение слов типа куча становится более обобщённым и менее связанным с конкретными предметами и материалами, что проявляется в расширении их сочетаемости (ср. куча песку, куча людей).
В настоящем докладе речь пойдет не о семантике, а о морфолого-синтаксическом поведении названных квантификаторов, а именно об их способности выступать в форме аккузатива пару, кучу, массу в контекстах, не свойственных винительному падежу.
Рассматриваемое явление допустимо прежде всего в контекстах, в которых ожидается форма номинатива:

(1) Я думаю, что от силы эти фильмы видело пару тысяч человек со всего СНГ. [alec-milkin.livejournal.com/131702.html]

(2) с того времени осталось кучу положительных эмоций – Хеппи Мил, желтый клоун, Москва, Арбат, детство. [www.juravsky.ru] (Здесь и далее сохранена пунктуация оригинала.)
Носители языка широко употребляют аккузатив таким образом и в устной речи, следовательно, об опечатке речь идти не может.

Однако контекстами номинатива дело не ограничивается: в Интернете есть и примеры, в которых форма аккузатива заменяет, например, датив или генитив при предлогах:

(3) Спросив у пару человек, далеко ли идти до Старого Барлака получаем приблизительную картину. [www.fishingsib.ru/tidings/310]

Впрочем, данные примеры при опросе носителей часто оцениваются как неграмматичные.

Рассматриваемая конструкция обладает некоторыми особенностями, нетипичными для русских количественных конструкций с существительным в вершине.
Во-первых, когда в позиции субъекта употребляется форма типа пару, согласование с ней может быть по единственному числу и среднему роду или по множественному числу:

(4) в самом начале карьеры, в 98 году кажется, у неё было пару песен на русском... [http://www.euroforum.com.ru/read.php?7,348324,348332,quote=1]

(5) После были еще пару песен. [vkontakte.ru/notes.php?id=41190162]

Во-вторых, в конструкции с пару (и в меньшей мере с другими квантификаторами) возможно определение в форме родительного падежа множественного числа:

(6) Осталось всего каких-то пару часиков. [http://www.24open.ru/Aleksey4444011/blog /2636476]

Поведение пару в рассматриваемой конструкции очень похоже на поведение собственно русских числительных типа пять или кванторов типа несколько. Можно заметить следующие общие черты:

 числительные, как правило, не различают именительный и винительный падежи:

(7) а. Там было пять женщин.
б. Я встретил там пять женщин.

 числительные допускают согласование глагола как по множественному числу, так и по единственному числу среднего рода:

(8) Уцелело / уцелели только два дома.

 числительные допускают определение в генитиве множественного числа:

(9) Каких-то два дома.

(10) Целых сто человек.

К числу других свойств, сближающих квантификаторы рассматриваемой группы с числительными, относятся допустимость зависимой словоформы человек (ср. пять человек, пара человек при недопустимости *толпа человек), а также маргинальная допустимость согласования с зависимым по падежу квантификатора пара (пяти людям, паре людям, *толпе людям).

Таким образом, можно предположить, что использование единой морфологической формы в контекстах, требующих номинатива и аккузатива, является одним из ряда формальных свойств числительных, приобретаемых рассматриваемыми квантификаторами. Важно отметить, что при этом исходно морфологическое неразличение форм, по всей видимости, становится свойством синтаксической конструкции.

Ответ на вопрос, почему именно форма аккузатива переосмысляется как дефолтная и расширяет своё употребление, до конца не ясен. Возможно, этому переосмыслению способствовало распространение допустимой в литературном языке конструкции, в которой атрибутивное зависимое, используемое с существительным пара в винительном падеже, стоит в форме множественного числа (11). Данные НКРЯ (Национальный корпус русского языка, ruscorpora.ru) показывают, что в XX веке частотность этой конструкции увеличилась.

(11) А когда подъехали к отелю, вдруг неожиданно гнусавым голосом стал выпрашивать всю сумму целиком, а не то, что он заработал за эти пару часов. [Марина Москвина. Небесные тихоходы: путешествие в Индию (2003)] (НКРЯ)
В данной конструкции происходит семантическое согласование атрибутивного зависимого, из-за чего исходная грамматическая характеристика слова пара (единственное число) как бы размывается, что облегчает понимание формы пару как дефолтной. Заметим, что для формы именительного падежа пара такой переход затруднен, поскольку, судя по данным НКРЯ, атрибутивные зависимые при ней значительно реже стоят в форме множественного числа.

В итоге можно констатировать, что параллельно с семантическим размыванием и расширением дистрибуции существительных типа пара, куча, масса происходит изменение их грамматических свойств в сторону свойств числительных. Одним из таких свойств оказывается допустимость рассматриваемой конструкции.
Литература

Рахилина Е. В, Су Хён Ли. Семантика лексической множественности в русском языке // Вопросы языкознания, №4, 2009.

Су Хён Ли. Когнитивный анализ русских конструкций с именными квантификаторами. Дисс. … канд. филол. наук. М.: РГГУ, 2005.

Comment: Спасибо! Ну вот и подтверждение того, что мне ничего не мерещилось и что я действительно часто это слышу. А то некоторые сомневались.