# Прошла пара лет/месяцев — нормально так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь

[Тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467612/%D0%A1-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%AF%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D1%80/467613?noredirect=1#comment486411_467613) в комментариях у нас зашёл разговор об этом.

Ксения [отсюда](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/424504/%D0%91%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D1%83-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) даже не слышала, чтобы говорили иначе. И [вот](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427535/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%90-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%9E-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE) ещё мой вопрос на эту тему.

Вот подборка комментариев:

> @Rusletov А почему не перевести на русский как «Прошло всего парА месяцев с тех пор, как вы РАБОТАЕТЕ»? — **Егор**
> @ЕгорСальков Говорят "всего парУ месяцев". Похожий пример: пару дней назад. — **oleedd**
> Прошла всего пара месяцев — согласование понятно, но разве так говорят? "Пару" имеет значение "несколько" (примерное количество), что указано в словаре, а "пара" — это конкретно два. — **oleedd**
> В словаре не указано, что "пару" означает "несколько", а "пара" — нет. Про падеж и речи нету, это было бы абсурдно. — **я**
> @АртёмЛуговой Такие примеры? Прошла всего пара месяцев. Прошла всего пара дней. Прошла всего пара минут. Прошла всего пара секунд. Прошла всего пара лет. У вас так говорят? У нас — нет. Обрати внимание на последний пример, он самый ужасный. У вас точно так говорят? Или корректны все, или не корректно ничего. — **oleedd**
> Я уже начал сомневаться) — **я**

Answer (score 0):

:) Желающие могут также почитать, что думает [Розенталь](https://litresp.ru/chitat/ru/%D0%A0/rozentalj-ditmar-eljyashevich/spravochnik-po-pravopisaniyu-i-literaturnoj-pravke-dlya-rabotnikov-pechati/221) (который, кажется, кого-то не устраивает, — и я даже догадываюсь, кого и почему):

> **14.**  В единственном числе ставится сказуемое при существительных со значением неопределенного количества (масса, уйма, бездна, пропасть и т.п.). При этом возможны варианты согласования в роде; ср.: *Народу **сбежалось бездна...*** (Л. Толстой). – *Дел у него **была бездна...*** (Чернышевский). Обычно препозитивное сказуемое стоит в форме среднего рода, а постпозитивное сказуемое согласуется с указанными существительными; ср.: *В моей повести **было бездна** натянутого* (Герцен) – **Уйма** трудностей **пережита...** (В. Панова).

А *пара* (в отличие от *два/две*), если речь не о чём-то вроде пары туфель или супружеской пары, то есть не о комплекте, не о двух объектах, мыслящихся как единое целое, — это именно существительное со значением неопределённого количества!

Или этот вопрос был не о глаголе? Но разве можно **всерьёз обсуждать подлежащее в косвенном падеже?!** *Ждали пару минут, прожили вместе пару лет* — тут всё нормально: *пара* — объект и дополнение. Но если *пара* **сама** *прошла,* так она же, чёрт возьми, субъект!

Comment: Вопрос и о глаголе, и о падеже "пары". Я с вами согласен в последнем абзаце, но ведь есть несогласные (по крайней мере один oleedd).

Comment: Я полагаю, мнения несогласных со здравым смыслом не должно принимать во внимание.

Comment: А почему нельзя всерьез обсуждать подлежащее в косвенном падеже? _Мне_ так _не кажется_ :)

Comment: Потому что подлежащее не бывает в косвенном падеже. И всё то, что стоит в косвенном падеже — не подлежащее.  А кому кажется, что что-то из этого — подлежащее, тот пусть перекрестится.

Comment: А почему не бывает? Вот вам предложения: мне плохо, мне кажется, Васе дурно... Какие тут подлежащие?

Comment: @Aer «А почему не бывает?» — если это вопрос о причине, то ответ: так договорились. (А договорились так потому, что если бы подлежащее могло быть в любом падеже, то его в предложениях вообще было бы не найти.) А если вопрос риторический и вы считаете, что привели примеры подлежащих в косвенном падеже, то разочаруйтесь: их тут нет. Это односоставные безличные предложения,  — т. е. предложения, в которых есть только сказуемое. В первом и третьем предложениях сказуемое выражено предикативным наречием, во втором — личным глаголом, перешедшим в безличную форму.

Comment: Боюсь, что ваша позиция весьма узка и догматична. Полистайте [эту](https://clck.ru/XfUwE) презентацию, например, или [вот](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/est-li-v-russkom-yazyke-sententsialnye-podlezhaschie) статья на схожу тему. И, конечно, у подлежащего есть разнообразные критерии (работающие не только в русском языке). Их применение к русскому материалу вкратце изложено в этой презентации: https://studfile.net/preview/6268307/. Так что ваша формулировка чересчур строга («Но разве можно всерьёз обсуждать подлежащее в косвенном падеже?!»).

Comment: Хорошо: обсуждайте возможность существования подлежащих в косвенных падежах. Можете заодно обсудить возможность существования рая и ада. Но обсуждать всё это вы будете с кем-то другим, а не со мной.

Comment: Где о вариантах окончаний -а, -у? Вопрос об этом, и с этого всё началось.

Comment: О вариантах окончаний -а, -у — в статьях и презентациях от Aer'a.

Comment: А должно быть у вас в ответе. Но этого не будет (не найдёте), потому что окончание -а в подобных сочетаниях некорректно, а член предложения роли не играет.

Comment: Ссылку на РАН или на Розенталя в доказательство того, что «окончание -а в подобных сочетаниях некорректно, а член предложения роли не играет», — без такой ссылки эта версия не пройдёт.

Comment: А Розенталь и РАН не станут разбирать все некорректные варианты. Как вы себе это представляете? Разбор всех возможных ошибок? Они говорят лишь о том, что возможно. Было бы возможно, вы бы уже давно нашли.